# Unexpected EXC_BAD with NSNumber

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, exc-bad-access

I am trying to observe a BOOL property of an view.
Because there are different kinds of view to observe, I check the selector and use performSelector to get value.

```
if( [tab respondsToSelector:@selector(canGoBack)] ) {
  [tab addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"canGoBack" 
    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
    context:NULL];
  NSNumber* value = (NSNumber*)[tab performSelector:@selector(canGoBack)];
  canGoBack = [value boolValue];
}
```

However, I got EXC_BAD accidentally at "[value boolValue]".
I checked the tab, it did exist when the error occurred.

After I changed the code to the following, the error has never been caught again.

```
  if( [tab respondsToSelector:@selector(canGoBack)] ) {
    [tab addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"canGoBack" 
      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
      context:NULL];
      canGoBack = [tab canGoBack];
//    NSNumber* value = (NSNumber*)[tab performSelector:@selector(canGoBack)];
//    canGoBack = [value boolValue];
  }
```

I wonder, why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you using canGoBack as function and also as bool value. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

because your method `canGoBack` returns a `BOOL` while `performSelector:` expects a return value of type `id`. the result of BOOL will not be an address of a valid objc object, which you cast it as, then use to send an objc message with.

Comment: If it is just a random address, why the value is always right when there is no EXC_BAD?  Is there any auto cast mechanism?

Comment: @Slavik the address may be predictable, but is useless and definitely going to cause undefined behavior if you attempt to use a signed char result as an objc object. there is no auto-cast in this case because there is no way to cast a signed char as an objc object. you could create your own function which uses NSInvocation (or the interfaces in `obc/`), if you want to achieve something functionally comparable.

Comment: Thank you.
BTW, is there any comment for behavior of performSelector when the return value is no a NSObject.

Comment: @Slavik it's mentioned in the docs, as well as the use of NSInvocation when the result/arguments are not objc types. so, you'll have to use an alternative i mentioned to accomplish this correctly. good luck

Answer (score 0):

canGoBack is selector method and you trying to assign a bool value to that method? how can it be possible?..
and second think ,are you sure the NSNumber you are getting is only 1 or 0, otherwise typecasting NSNumber t o bool is not use full

Comment: canGoBack is declared as property.
The objc will generate a get method for the property.
For that reason, it could response to @selector(canGoBack).
I am trying to get a bool value from that method?

However I found it could success for most of the time.  Then why does it fail?

Comment: u already mentioned canGoBack is a method..you cannot assign a value into a method